# How do I show that the Petersen graph has 15 edges?

Tags: graph-theory

The Petersen graphs vertices consist of all two element subsets of $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \rbrace$ so $V={5\choose 2}=10$. Vertices are adjacent if the intersection of two vertices is empty e.g. $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace \cap \lbrace 3, 4 \rbrace = \emptyset$ so $\lbrace \lbrace 1, 2\rbrace, \lbrace 3, 4 \rbrace \rbrace=\lbrace \lbrace 3, 4\rbrace, \lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace \rbrace$ is an edge. Clearly $E\subseteq {10\choose 2}=45$ but the number of edges is 15. Does it relate to $\frac{10\choose 2}{3}$? I don't really see why this would be. I just can't think of how to actually show it is 15 by a counting argument.

Comment: I think you mean $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}=\{\{3,4\},\{1,2\}\}$ is an edge.

Comment: As sets, $\{1,2,3,4\}=\{1,3,2,4\}=\{1,4,2,3\},$ but $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\},\ \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\},$ and $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}$ are three different edges.

Comment: @bof yes that’s what I meant to put. Thanks

Comment: Since there are $3$ ways to split $4$ numbers into two pairs, another way to count the edges is $3\cdot\binom54=15.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the vertex $\{1,2\}$ is linked to the three vertices $\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}$ - there are three remaining digits so $\binom 32$ vertices to which any particular vertex is linked - and then it is simple to count.

Comment: Ahh, very simple. Thank you.